# Need Help _ Error - can't compute values and eliminate those with 0's

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I try to compute values in the end, it shows me an error. I can't figure it out, why? It works without sum at the end of the query. I would like to compute values and eliminate those that show 0.

```sql
SELECT ime_priimek, 
       ( 
              SELECT Count (avtor) 
              FROM   dolzniki_klici 
              WHERE  dolzniki_klici.avtor = uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    dolzniki_klici.datum >='2020-03-01' 
              AND    dolzniki_klici.datum<='2020-03-31') AS vsi_klici, 
       ( 
              SELECT Count(avtor) 
              FROM   dolzniki_klici 
              WHERE  dolzniki_klici.avtor = uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    status_klica='1' 
              AND    dolzniki_klici.datum >='2020-03-01' 
              AND    dolzniki_klici.datum<='2020-03-31') AS uspesni_klici, 
       ( 
              SELECT Count (dolzniki_dogovori.id) 
              FROM   dolzniki_dogovori 
              WHERE  dolzniki_dogovori.id_uporabnik = uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    dolzniki_dogovori.datum_nastavljeno>='2020-03-01' 
              AND    dolzniki_dogovori.datum_nastavljeno<='2020-03-31') AS st_dogovorov, 
       ( 
              SELECT Count (dolzniki_opravila.opravil_uporabnik) 
              FROM   dolzniki_opravila 
              WHERE  dolzniki_opravila.opravil_uporabnik=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    reseno_opravilo IS NOT NULL 
              AND    datum_opravljeno >='2020-03-01' 
              AND    datum_opravljeno <='2020-03-31') AS opravljena_opravila, 
       ( 
              SELECT Count(avtor) 
              FROM   dolzniki_izhodna_posta 
              WHERE  dolzniki_izhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    posta ilike '%PRIJAVA TERJATVE V%' 
              AND    datum>='2020-03-01' 
              AND    datum<='2020-03-31') AS prijavljeni_stecaji, 
       ( 
              SELECT count(avtor) 
              FROM   dolzniki_vhodna_posta 
              WHERE  dolzniki_vhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    datum_pregledano>='2020-03-01' 
              AND    datum_pregledano<='2020-03-31') AS pregledana_posta, 
       ( 
              SELECT count(avtor) 
              FROM   dolzniki_vhodna_posta 
              WHERE  dolzniki_vhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    datum_vpisa>='2020-03-01' 
              AND    datum_vpisa<='2020-03-31') AS vpisana_posta, 
       ( 
              SELECT count(avtor) 
              FROM   dolzniki_izhodna_posta 
              WHERE  dolzniki_izhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
              AND    datum>='2020-03-01' 
              AND    datum<='2020-03-31') AS poslana_posta, 
       ( 
              SELECT (vsi_klici+uspesni_klici+st_dogovorov+opravljena_opravila+prijavljeni_stecaji+pregledana_posta+vpisana_posta+poslana_posta) AS kalkulacija
              FROM   ( 
                            SELECT 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count (avtor) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_klici 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_klici.avtor = uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
                                          AND    dolzniki_klici.datum >='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    dolzniki_klici.datum<='2020-03-31') AS vsi_klici, 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count(avtor) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_klici 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_klici.avtor = uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
                                          AND    status_klica='1' 
                                          AND    dolzniki_klici.datum >='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    dolzniki_klici.datum<='2020-03-31') AS uspesni_klici, 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count (dolzniki_dogovori.id) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_dogovori 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_dogovori.id_uporabnik = uporabniki.id_uporabnik
                                          AND    dolzniki_dogovori.datum_nastavljeno>='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    dolzniki_dogovori.datum_nastavljeno<='2020-03-31') AS st_dogovorov, 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count (dolzniki_opravila.opravil_uporabnik) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_opravila 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_opravila.opravil_uporabnik=uporabniki.id_uporabnik
                                          AND    reseno_opravilo IS NOT NULL 
                                          AND    datum_opravljeno >='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    datum_opravljeno <='2020-03-31') AS opravljena_opravila, 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count(avtor) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_izhodna_posta 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_izhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik
                                          AND    posta ilike '%PRIJAVA TERJATVE V%' 
                                          AND    datum>='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    datum<='2020-03-31') AS prijavljeni_stecaji, 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count(avtor) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_vhodna_posta 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_vhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik
                                          AND    datum_pregledano>='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    datum_pregledano<='2020-03-31') AS pregledana_posta, 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count(avtor) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_vhodna_posta 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_vhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik
                                          AND    datum_vpisa>='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    datum_vpisa<='2020-03-31') AS vpisana_posta, 
                                   ( 
                                          SELECT count(avtor) 
                                          FROM   dolzniki_izhodna_posta 
                                          WHERE  dolzniki_izhodna_posta.avtor=uporabniki.id_uporabnik
                                          AND    datum>='2020-03-01' 
                                          AND    datum<='2020-03-31') AS poslana_posta) AS table1) 
FROM   uporabniki 
WHERE  lokalni_uporabnik=true 
AND    kalkulacija >'0'
```

EDIT:
Formated Query, this should be looks like readable.
This is the raw query that was being executed from the terminal.

Comment: This is one big query.  With nothing to go on - I suggest you see if kalkulacija is a number and perhaps change the condition to kalkulacija>0.  If that doesn't work, you really should give the error you are getting and table definitions perhaps.  Without more info it is difficult to help.

Comment: Format your query, it will help you out resolving issues, and encourage us to look closer at it. Your description leads me to assume the column "kalkulacija"  is calculated (selected) and used in the where clause at the same level as selected. If this the case you cannot use it because the where clause is evaluated before the select phase calculates it so it does not exist for the where clause; you will need to the where to the next higher layer in the overall statement.

Comment: You need to mention the issue, here. And please don't post such queries like that. We are not here to write the query for you.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I've resolved my issue, I've chosen SELECT *, put the whole query into () and kalkulacija > 0 outside. And it worked. Thanks Belayer and Mayur.